# PHP - Undefined variable when sub total the price - Shopping cart

Tags: php, arrays, magento, shopping-cart, cart

```
<?php
session_start();
```

**Connection**

```
mysql_connect ('localhost', 'Akram', '') or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('cart'); 
$page=("index.php");
```

**Quantity**

```
if (isset($_GET['add'])){
    $quantity = mysql_query('SELECT id, quantity FROM products WHERE id='. mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['add']));
    while ($quantity_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($quantity)){
                if ($quantity_row['quantity']!=$_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]){
                    $_SESSION['cart_'.$_GET['add']]+='1';
        }   
    }
}
```

**To show the product list**

```
function products (){
    $get = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM products');
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get)){
                    echo '<p>' .$row ['name']. '</br>'.$row['price'].'</br>'.$row['quantity'].'<br/>'.$row['description']. '<br/>'.'<a href="cart.php?add='.$row['id'].'">'.'Add to cart'.'</a>'.'</p>';
    }
}
```

**Show the product in shopping cart**

```
    function cart ()    {
        foreach($_SESSION as $name => $value)   {
            if ($value>0)   {
                if (substr($name, 0,5)=='cart_')    {
                    $id = substr($name, 5, (strlen ($name)-5));
                    $get = mysql_query('SELECT id, name, price FROM products WHERE id='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$id));
                    while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))  {
                        $sub = $get_row ['price']*$value;
                        echo $get_row['name']  .  ' X ' . $value . ' @ &pound;' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2) . ' = ' . '&pound'.number_format($sub, 2). '<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">'.'[REMOVE]'.'</a>'. '<a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">'.'[ADD]'.'</a>'. '<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">'.'[DELETE]'.'</a>';
                    }       
                }
                    $total += $sub; //getting error Undefined variable
            }
        }
if ($total==0) { //getting error Undefined variable
    echo "your cart is empty!";
}
else {
    echo 'Total: &pound;'. number_format($total, 2);
    //PayPal Button here
}
}
```

**ADD , Remove and Delete buttons**

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_' .(int)$_GET['add']]+='1';
    header('Location: ' .$page);
}

if (isset($_GET['remove'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_' . (int)$_GET['remove']]--;
    header('Location: ' .$page);
}

if (isset($_GET['delete'])){
    $_SESSION['cart_' .(int)$_GET['delete']]='0';
    header('Location: ' .$page);
}


?>
```

I am trying to get the total price of all items after added them into bucket but i am having undefined variable error with $total var.

Comment: General tip for SO. Try and avoid large code dumps like this. Instead only show what you think is the relevant code. If you don't show enough we will ask for more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a problem with `$total += $sub` being in the wrong place.

You should move it into the mysql_fetch, so that the total applies for every item in the query.

```
while ($get_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($get))  {
    $sub = $get_row ['price']*$value;
    echo $get_row['name']  .  ' X ' . $value . ' @ &pound;' . number_format($get_row['price'], 2) . ' = ' . '&pound'.number_format($sub, 2). '<a href="cart.php?remove='.$id.'">'.'[REMOVE]'.'</a>'. '<a href="cart.php?add='.$id.'">'.'[ADD]'.'</a>'. '<a href="cart.php?delete='.$id.'">'.'[DELETE]'.'</a>';
    $total += $sub; //added it here
}
```

You should also initialize `$total` to 0, so when there are no items in the query, (i.e no items in the cart), it will say there's no items in the cart.

So something like:

```
function cart () {
    $total = 0;
```

This will then fix your problem of having an unset variable later on for:

```
if ($total==0) { //getting error Undefined variable
    echo "your cart is empty!";
}
```